# App desktop, usando electron e nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso passar o valor de um campo que está em (index.html) para uma função que está (data-user.js).

Tenho uma aplicação em nodejs usando electron, o main chama o index.html, que monte a tela, e tem alguns campos, NOME, EMAIL e um botão.
Quando pressionar o botão quero enviar o valor dos campos para uma função que está em uma classe (.js).

```
    <form method="post" action=""> 
      <h1>Ativar Notificações</h1> 

      <p> 
        <label for="nome_cad">Seu nome</label>
        <input id="nome_cad" name="nome_cad" required="required" type="text" placeholder="nome" />
      </p>

      <p> 
        <label for="email_cad">Seu e-mail</label>
        <input id="email_cad" name="email_cad" required="required" type="email" placeholder="example@email.com"/> 
      </p>

      <p>
        <button onclick="sendData()" > Ativar </button>
      </p>
    </form>
```

Estou tentando fazer assim, mas não funcionou:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sendData(){
    const dataUser = require('./data-user');

    dataUser(document.getElementById('nome_cad').value,  document.getElementById('email_cad').value);

  }

</script>
```

A classe data-user, esta assim:

```
module.exports = async (nome, email) => {

console.log(nome);
console.log(email);

}
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta

```
<script src="./data-user.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sendData(){
  dataUser(document.getElementById('nome_cad').value,  document.getElementById('email_cad').value);

  }
</script>
```

E no `./data-user.js`

```
function dataUser(nome, email){
  console.log(nome);
  console.log(email);
}
```